# Which way to append dict to list is more efficient

Tags: python

```
# Method one
array_a = []
a = {}
for i in range(5):
    a = {}
    a[str(i)] = i
    array_a.append(a)
print(array_a)
# [{'0': 0}, {'1': 1}, {'2': 2}, {'3': 3}, {'4': 4}]

# Method two    
from copy import deepcopy
array_b = []
b = {}
for i in range(5):
    b.clear()
    b[str(i)] = i
    array_b.append(deepcopy(b))
print(array_b)
# [{'0': 0}, {'1': 1}, {'2': 2}, {'3': 3}, {'4': 4}]
```

I would like to know which one of above is more efficient.
And, if you have a better one, please let me know.

Comment: Have you tested this?  ipython has a really great `timeit` command that makes this quite easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is not relevant. Both need to create a new dict each time. Since the first is clearer, it is preferable over the second method.

My suggestion would be a list comprehension:

```
array_c = [{str(i): i} for i in range(5)]
```

Comment: Agreed.  The list comp is equivalent and much more concise.  Also it looks cool :)

Comment: I am not able to use this list comprehension since my logical is very complicate and will be hard to ready if put everything in compact format. The OP just gives a demo that I want to know the good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner that should also be more efficient:

```
array_a.extend([{str(i): i} for i in xrange(5)])
```

Or via map():

```
array_a.extend(map(lambda i: {str(i): i}, xrange(5)))
```